# How to implement java typed array in native c++ jni

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have an array of a class type defined in java.
I'm trying to use that class typed array in native c++ JNI and prepare c++ parcel object from it.

Below is my class structure in java:

```
public class MyIdentifier implements Parcelable {

    private String abc;
    private String def;

    public MyIdentifier(String abc, String def) {
        this(abc, def);
    }
}
```

and that's the java function I want to invoke from c++

```
 public int setident(List<MyIdentifier> ident) throws RemoteException {
                Parcel _data = Parcel.obtain();
                Parcel _reply = Parcel.obtain();
                try {
                    _data.writeInterfaceToken(Stub.DESCRIPTOR);
                    _data.writeTypedList(ident);
                    this.mRemote.transact(169, _data, _reply, 0);
                    _reply.readException();
                    return _reply.readInt();
                } finally {
                    _reply.recycle();
                    _data.recycle();
                }
            }
```

Comment: The natural way would be to create an ArrayList of MyIdentifier objects on the C++ side on the fly. But if such list is coming to C++ from Java, it would be easier to store it on the C++ side as global reference, even if it may require some manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to invoke `Arrays.asList(javaList)` from C++.
Here I assume you have `array_of_MyIdentifier` as a `jobject`:

```cpp
jobject array_of_MyIdentifier = ...;
jclass Arrays = env->FindClass("java/util/Arrays");
jmethodID Arrays_asList = env->GetStaticMethodID(Arrays, "asList", "([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;");
jobject arrayList = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(Arrays, Arrays_asList, array_of_MyIdentifier);
```